# Generate cucumber examples programmatically in when statement

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have the following scenario -

```
  Scenario: View the urls and verify
    Given I want to run "User view"
    When I navigate to the url //This step generates multiple urls
    Then the element <name> is visible
    And the element <different name> should have the text
```

The `when` step generates multiple urls, and we need to run the then and and steps on all the generated URls. Is this possible?

One way of doing so was to generate example table dynamically, however I found examples where the examples are being read from csv or excels, are there other ways of doing this?